# Pushouts for putting together structures

Tags: category-theory

In Sannella and Tarlecki book "Foundations of algebraic specification and formal software development" they describe pushouts as:

> Pushouts provide a basic tool for putting together structures of various kinds. Given two objects $A$ and $B$, a pair of morphisms $f:C \rightarrow A$  and $g: C \rightarrow B$ indicates a common source from which "parts" of A and B come. The pushout of $f$ and $g$ puts together $A$ and $B$ while identifying the parts coming from the common source as indicated by $f$ and $g$, but keeping the new parts disjoint.

My question is about the last line. I understand that a pushout puts $A$ and $B$ together but I dont understand what they mean when they say that it's able to identify parts from $C$ and that it keep the new parts disjoint.

I understand that this is a very specific question, thank you for any help.

Comment: I think the quoted text is not meant to be taken "too literary", but seems rather to be some hand waving meant to provide intuition. I guess it is followed or preceded by some more formal definition. Try to understand this definition, not the quoted text, as I think it's rather confusing. That is, I kind of see how it is meant to be read, but I think it can be easily read completely differently. Thus, if you are lost, it might be a good idea to switch to a completely different explanation.

Comment: @NeitherNor Yes absolutely. It is right after the definition of pushout. I think I feel comfortable with the formal definition but I was wondering about this part of the text of course intuitive descriptions arent formal but they often help me understand the "idea". Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are sets, and that $f \colon C \to A$ and $g \colon C \to B$ are functions between these sets.
We have two kinds of elements in $A$: those elements which lie in the image of $f$ (and  thus come from $C$ via the map $f$) and those elements that don’t lie in this image.
This gives us a disjoint union
$$
  \newcommand{\dcup}{\mathbin{\dot{\cup}}}
  A = (A ∖ f(C)) \dcup f(C) \,.
$$
Let us abbreviate the set $A ∖ f(C)$ as $A'$, so that
$$
  A = A' \dcup f(C) \,.
$$
We have similarly the disjoint union
$$
  B = B' \dcup g(C)
  \quad \text{where} \quad
  B' = B ∖ g(C) \,.
$$

The sets $f(C)$ and $g(C)$ are the “parts” that come from $C$, whereas the sets $A'$ and $B'$ are the “new parts”.

The pushout in question will be of the form
$$
  A' \dcup I \dcup B' \,,
$$
with the set $I$ given by $(f(C) \amalg g(C)) / {∼}$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by the conditions $f(x) ∼ g(x)$ for all $x ∈ C$.
Intuitively speaking, the set $I$ arises by putting the two sets $f(C)$ and $g(C)$ right next to each other, and then stitching them together so that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ become the same (in $I$).
We thus “identify” $f(x)$ with $g(x)$ for every $x ∈ C$.

We see that the pushout consists of three disjoints parts: the new parts $A'$ and $B'$, and the identified part $I$.
We see in particular that $A'$ and $B'$ stay disjoint.

Comment: This made a lot of sense to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider, as a (very artificial) example, where I've made a slight effort to imagine when a pushout might be relevant in formal software development: $C$ is the integers, $A$ is the set of red vectors of integers, $B$ is the set of blue vectors of integers. (Red and blue mean whatever you want here: abstract labels, how they're displayed on a terminal, whatever.) Let the maps $f:C\to A$ and $g:C\to B$ send each integer to the corresponding length-$1$ vector. Then the pushout is the union of $A$ and $B,$ modulo the equivalence relation identifying $f(n)$ with $g(n)$ for every integer $n.$ That means it consists of two *almost* disjoint copies of the set of all vectors–red and blue vectors sitting in the same place–except that red and blue vectors of length $1$ become indistinguishable. Thus the "parts from $C$" (the length-1 vectors) have been identified, but the rest (red vectors and blue vectors of length greater than $1$) have been kept disjoint.

Comment: Say, C is a length-2 vector, and $f$ sends its first element to a length-1 vector in the set of red vectors A, and $g$ its second element to a length-1 vector in the set of blue vectors B. How does the pushout look like?